# Return PPT Object in Function

Tags: excel, vba

I just wrote the following function to create and return a powerpoint object:

```
Public Function Open_PowerPoint_Presentation(ByVal ppName As String) As Object

Dim objPPT As Object
Dim Path As String
Path = ThisWorkbook.Path

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True

Open_PowerPoint_Presentation = objPPT.Presentations.Open Path & "\Reports\" & ppName & ".pptx"

End Function
```

But the last line (`Open_PowerPoint_PResentation =` ...) gives me an "Compile Error" and I just dont know why. Could anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to:

`Set Open_PowerPoint_Presentation = objPPT.Presentations.Open(Path & "\Reports\" & ppName & ".pptx")`

The `Set` keyword is needed to assign the object to a variable, and the brackets are part of the syntax for assigning a method return (in this case `Open`) to a variable.